# How to update status automaticaly when all relations are done?

Tags: laravel

I have two models like

```
Model A { 
   id 
   name 
   is_completed 
}
```

and

```
Model B { 
   id 
   name 
   is_completed 
   model_a_id 
}
```

`Model_A` have realtion with `Model_`B as `hasMany(`)

I want to update the `is_completed = true` of Model_A automatically when all Model_Bs with the same `model_a_id` are `is_completed = true`

Could you advice any best approaches to do this?

I would apprecieate any kind of help! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could execute an event closure whenever `Model B`s are [updated](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events-using-closures):

```php
class ModelB extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::updated(function ($model_b) {
            if ($model_b->model_a->is_completed) {
                return;
            }
            foreach ($model_b->model_a->model_bs as $model) {
                if (!$model->is_completed) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            $model_b->model_a->update(['is_completed' => true]);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: wow! thanks for the quick response! Just a question what do you think about perfomance? I just made some research and findout about Events. What do you think is it too complicated to use events or in my case it is enough to use your implementation?

Comment: Whether your event runs here or within an Event class doesn't matter as far as performance is concerned.  However if you need to do significantly more work each update, I would look into using a queued job (especially if the data doesn't need to be returned right away).

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it :)